# Add body class to the page or post or even cpt page where my shortcode is added

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a body class to whatever page (page, post or cpt) my shortcode is added. Been googling and binging with no luck, thanks in advance.

Comment: Changed Ask to Add, apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn to use Google better :)

```
function my_body_class( $classes ) {

    global $post;

    if( isset($post->post_content) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'your-shortcode' ) ) {
        $classes [] = 'your-class';
    }
    return $classes ;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class' );
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141321/adding-body-class-when-post-contains-a-specific-shortcode

But read the notes in regards to caching... doing something like this is "taxing" on the server and could probably be done better, or not at all.  If you can give more details as to WHY you need to do this, I can offer some alternative suggestions.

Comment: Basically I am trying to utilize a css of an existing plugin, how ever as I checked this plugin's css, I see body.plugin_class, basically the css structure is deep in heirarchy and has that (body.plugin_class) in it to apply the styling. Thats why I need to add a class to whatever page my shortcode is added.

Comment: Also note I could easily just copy and paste the css from that plugin, but I want a much cleaner solution, also the css are quite long

Comment: Also just to clarify, I want to be consistent with this plugin's css styling, so if this plugin updates it's styling, I'll benefit from that, rather than edit my "copied" css.